# Using variables inside terraform.tfvars file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to create VPC subnet tags using map variable.

Getting below error while passing value from locals tag in the terraform.tfvars file.

```
"Variables may not be used here"
```

I want to pass values from tfvars file instead of setting a default value for subnet_tags variable in the variables.tf file.

Below are the details.

```
variables.tf:

variable "project_name" {   
  type        = string
}

variable "subnet_tags" {  
  description = "public subnets"
  type        = map
} 

---------------------------------------------------------

terraform.tfvars:

subnet_tags={
    "project"                                   = "${local.project_name}"
    "environment"                               = "development"
    "managed-by"                                = "terraform"
    "role"                                      = "public"    
    }

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

main.tf:

locals {
  project_name = var.project_name 

}

module "vpc" {
  source      = "../modules/vpc 
  subnet_tags = var.subnet_tags 
  ...
  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `merge` [1] built-in function. Variables cannot be used inside tfvars file as you can see. So in your case, to combine two different sets of tags, you could drop the `project` tag from the `subnet_tags` variable:

```
subnet_tags={
    "environment"                               = "development"
    "managed-by"                                = "terraform"
    "role"                                      = "public"    
    }
```

And then in the module call, just use `merge` and the `project` tag:

```
module "vpc" {
  source      = "../modules/vpc 
  subnet_tags = merge(
    { "project" = local.project_name },
    var.subnet_tags
   )
  ...
  
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge